# Is it possible to tell if `autoindent` is set or not in vim?

Tags: vim

I know I can use `set autoindent` and `set noautoindent` to enable and disable `autoindent`, but is it possible to ask vim, what is the current value of `autoindent`?

I already checked `:help autoindent` but it did not give any hints on this.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to show, set, and reset vim's variables:

```
:set            - shows vars different from defaults
:set all        - shows all values
:set foo?       - shows the value of foo
:set foo+=opt   - add opt to the value w/o changing others
:set foo-=opt   - remove opt from value
:set foo&       - reset foo to default value
:setlocal foo   - only the current buffer
```

`:help set` lists these options albeit in a rather verbose way.

Comment: Can also use `:verbose` to see where it was last set, e.g. `:verbose set autoindent?`

Answer (score 4):

You can query settable options with the question mark appended:

```
:set ai?
```

or more verbosely

```
:set autoindent?
```

If you want to query the value of *autoindent* in a vim function, you have to prepend the option name with an ampersand:

```
if &ai
   echo "yes, is set"
else
   echo "no, is not set"
end
```

In the same spirit, you can just

```
:echo &ai
```

which prints `1` if autoindent is set and `0` if it is not set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:set` to list all selected options. `autoindent` shows up if enabled.

I don't know if you can query if a specific option is set.